# How to find which programs are using up swap space

Tags: linux, memory, swap

How can I figure out which programs are using up swap space? My current memory usage is 2.9GiB out of 3.0GiB used(and I though I had 4GB, I need to check into that) and 1.3Gib of swap used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *top* type *fp* to add swap space display and then *Fp* to sort according to swap usage

Comment: Thanks. The numbers are not very correct(but I think I remember getting the correct number is not possible?) It said amarok was using over 700MB of swap, but when I closed it the amount of swap used barely dropped at all.

Comment: The value includes memory that is shared between different processes. 

You can use memstat -p PID to see the shared libs used by the process with the given PID along with their memory usage (total, not onyl swapped out).